# iOS Thread safety - Complete a block of code before thread switches

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsthread, synchronized

I'm looking for a way to make sure that some lines of code get always executed together (before the system may switch the thread).

@synchronized  does not work for this as far as I know since it will only block another thread to come into this certain block. In my example I have different code parts that take influence on each other and I want to make sure that each of them blocks the other.

How can this be achieved?

EDIT: One Use Case could be that I'm playing back a midi file. The events go out on a high priority thread automatically. While procoessing the single events the player could be stopped by the user. I want to make sure that either one note gets processed completely or that the player is stopped before and the notes doesn't go off.

Comment: If you have several "code parts" that block each other, my 1st attempt would be to have each of them in a @synchronize block. What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: Can you clarify? The concept of "before the system may switch the thread" doesn't make sense because the very idea of threads is that they operate concurrently with each other (which is why you use @synchronized (or other locking mechanisms) or dedicated serial queues to control [synchronization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1) of shared resources. Your question might be more clear if you were less abstract and, instead, described precisely what you're trying to do.

Comment: I added a use case of this ;)

Comment: @Max This sounds like less of an issue of thread-safety and more of an issue of how you interact with the libraries/frameworks you're employing for playback to ensure your midi playback's pause is deferred until the end of a note, tempo, etc. Unfortunately, that answer is highly dependent upon what library/framework you're using for playback, and I'd suggest you post a new question with all of those particulars (which library/framework, perhaps code samples, etc.).

Comment: When writing your own multi-threaded routines, you don't have to worry about a block of code not being "executed together" (as that's the standard behavior) and the question of thread-safety is generally accomplished with the synchronization techniques already discussed. But music playback libraries are a completely different beast, and unless I'm misunderstanding you, I'd suggest posting a new question on that very different topic.

Comment: Okay, thanks guys. I ended up writing my own midi player and not use any stuff I don't know how it works. Actually I just avoided threading problems by using the main thread when possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to **ensure** that your code is not preempted by the operating system. You have two options at you disposal to limit the possibility that this happens:

1. Run you code on a high priority thread. `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH);` will return such a queue. Code on this queue will run before code on any other lower priority queue. You still might get preempted though it is less likely.
2. Use locks, semaphores, @synchrosized or, as suggested by @Rob, a dedicated serial dispatch queue to serialize access to the critical code section. By doing so, no other thread will be able to run that piece of code until the other thread is done. If used correctly, this will guarantee that the code section is not executed by two threads concurrently.

Maybe you can tell us a bit more about your problem? With some code sample perhaps?