# Block switching thread in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, web-services, asynchronous

I have troubles with multiple threads. Here is the situation:

I make asynchronous requests to backend and, in some cases, need to cancel these. Canceling the requests happens in a separate thread. All requests to the backend are canceled and, as I exit a screen, multiple class instances are deallocated.

When I have the order request-cancel, everything works fine. However, sometimes the cancel method is invoked when I am already in the middle of the finish method (which needs a little bit time because of decoding and conversion of data). In such cases, the app crashes, a messages to deallocated instance is sent. It is not an exception that can be easily cached, I get the crash even when I check for the existence of the instances a line before. Actually, if I understand it right, the instance of the class where the finish and the cancel method are located, is deallocated. Nevermind, the problem is that the thread is switched in the middle of the finish method and I need to prevent that.

My question is: Is there a way to block switching the thread in the middle of a method? To declare this method as a whole (transaction)? Or is there another standard solution for such a problem?

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131591/ios-thread-safety-complete-a-block-of-code-before-thread-switches) but I don't really understand whether it can be used in my case or how to do that.

**EDIT: Canceling**

```
for (XXX *request in [XXX sharedQueue].operations)
{
    [request setDelegate:nil];
    [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:nil];
    [request setUploadProgressDelegate:nil];
    [request setQueue:nil];
    [request cancel];
}
```

`XXX` is the class used for the requests.

**Order of the methods**

Here is the order in which the methods are invoked (in the cases of error). `Handler` is the class for handling the requests.

```
Handler 1: make request
Handler 1: finish begin
Handler 2: cancel begin
Handler 2: cancel end
Handler 2: dealloc
Handler 1: dealloc
Handler 1: finish middle
```

Handler 1 and 2 are two instances of the class. The first one is deallocated in the middle of the finish method, so at the end of this I get a crash. Deallocating it is normal because after cancel I go to another view and basically everything gets deallocated.

My ideas for solution are either to somehow prevent going back to the finish method or to execute the entire finish method before switching the thread. Unfortunately, I have no idea how one of these could be implemented.

Comment: could you elaborate more on how the cancelling is done?

Comment: Sure, I added the code of the cancel method to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach might help you:

1. add a flag to your controller managing all requests;
2. when a request finish block is entered do like this:

   ```
   completionBlock:^() {
      @synchronized(self.myFinishFlag) {
          ...
      }
   }
   ```
3. in your cancel method do like this:

   ```
   -(void)userCancelledRequests:(id)sender {

      @synchronized(self.myFinishFlag) {
          ...
      }
   }
   ```

This will delay the execution of 'userCancelledRequests`body if a finish block is currently running (i.e., locking`self.myFinishFlag`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: But when I am in the cancel method, the request is already finished (as the finish method is invoked), so the request is no longer in the queue. How can I then check its flag? The problem is not the request itself, I don't need its response data. The problem is that some instance is deallocated by/after the cancelation method but I need it at the end of the finish method.

Comment: I see, then see my edited answer for a way to delay the request cancel execution.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the help. I didn't manage it solving my problem with recursiveLock/sync but I also don't really want to have it solved like that. In case of multiple requests and no cancel, that would be pretty bad for the app performance. But I used the idea for the flag. I added an `extern` variable to another class and I set it to `YES/NO` depending on whether I have executed cancel or not. In the `finish` method, I check the variable before doing something with `self`. Not the best possible solution (I suppose) but the app doesn't crash now. :)

Comment: happy to know that you fixed the issue. indeed, a mutex (@synchronized) is simply a flag that is set on/off. so you are implementing that kind of functionality on your own (without real thread-safety, but that is up to you to evaluate based on your requirements). not sure what you mean by app performance being hampered when no cancel is done, but that is another matter...

Comment: As far as I understand, `@synchronized` blocks the multiple execution of the code segment. I want that my `finish` method can be executed simultaneously when multiple requests return at the same time. I will check that again...

Comment: that is right if you are scheduling your finish blocks on a concurrent queue. in that case, you could `NSCondition` instead of the @synchronize directive to avoid the finish blocks to wait for another finish block to complete...

Comment: I changed my implementation and now I use lock and variable. I am pretty happy with that. I need the variable because the process is spread in multiple methods (one async request invokes another one etc). But you were right that I can use a lock without significant performance decrease, I think. Well, I will continue testing, but for now the problem is solved thanks to your help.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the `cancel` method of class `XXX` is not correctly implemented.

Suppose there is some asynchronous operation of type `XXX` which responds to a `cancel` message. In order to function reliable, the following requirements must be fulfilled:

1. The `cancel` message can be send from a client from *any* thread.
2. The `cancel` message can be send at *any* time and *multiple* times.
3. When the operation receives the `cancel` message, it stops it asynchronous task and cleans up itself properly at the next "cancelation point". Note: this may happen asynchronously with respect to the `cancel` method. The implementation needs to be "thread safe"!
4. The receiver shall notify the delegate that it has been cancelled (for example in a failure handler).
5. Furthermore, there should be no need for a caller to reset the delegate(s) or prepare the receiver in any way before sending the `cancel` message.

These requirements needs to be fulfilled by the implementation of class `XXX`.

Now, suppose you have an internal `finish` method for that operation and lets suppose that this is the last method which will be executed by the operation. When that method is executed, and when the operation receives a `cancel` message *concurrently*, the implementation must guarantee that the `cancel` has no effect, since it is *too* late: the last opportunity to cancel the operation has been passed. There are a number of ways how to accomplish this.

If this is true, then the following code should properly cancel your operations:

```
for (XXX *request in [XXX sharedQueue].operations) {
    [request cancel];
}
```

---

#### Edit:

Example for an "NSOperation like" implementation of a `cancel` and `finish` method:

Note:

Accessing *ivars* must be *synchronized*! Ivars will be accessed in various internal methods. All accesses will be serialized via a *private* serial dispatch queue, named "sync_queue".

```
- (void) cancel {
    dispatch_async(self.sync_queue, ^{
        if (_isCancelled || _isFinished) {
            return;
        }
        [self.task cancel];  // will sets _isCancelled to YES
        [self finish]; // will set _isFinished to YES
    });
}

- (void) finish 
{
    assert(<execution context equals sync_queue>);

    if (_isFinished) 
        return;

    completionHandler_t onCompletion = self.completionHandler;
    if (onCompletion) {
        id result = self.result;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
            onCompletion(result);
        });
    };

    self.completionHandler = nil;
    self.task = nil;
    self.isExecuting = NO;
    self.isFinished = YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! You are right that it is enough using `[request cancel]` and I don't need to set the delegates to `nil`. In the library that I am using for the requests, `cancel` is not invoked on the request for which I am already in the `finish` method. That was exactly my problem, I was not able to stop the request and I got a crash because of that. Now I found out how to prevent the crash. :)

Comment: @user2320456 Just notice: here, `finish` is a private method of the operation. It's the *last* action the operation will do. Also notice, that `finish` will be called in any case - even this has been caused by handling a `cancel` message. However, when the `finish` message has been entered "orderly" with the operation producing a result, the completion handler will be fired with that result. A *concurrently* occurring `cancel` received during `finish` has no effect on the operation (it's finished anyway) - and the `cancel` message won't also stop the completion handler.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to block is to perform all operations on a dedicated queue. When you want to cancel, do it like this:

```
dispatch_async(_someQueue, ^{
    for (XXX *request in [XXX sharedQueue].operations)
    {
        [request setDelegate:nil];
        [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:nil];
        [request setUploadProgressDelegate:nil];
        [request setQueue:nil];
        [request cancel];
    }
});
```

Then when the finished callback is triggered, you can do this:

```
dispatch_async(_someQueue, ^{
    if ([request isCancelled] == NO)
    {
        // Process request
    }
});
```

So long as _someQueue is not marked as a concurrent queue, this should do the trick.

Comment: When I am back in the finish method, the request is already finished. While I am decoding the data, the cancelation method is called. Because of the finish before, it is sure that the request is not canceled. What I want is to prevent going back to the finish method after some instances are already deallocated because of the cancel. So the answer doesn't really help me.